# Observable in for loop?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I would like to call an observable REST service in a for loop. It returns base64 encoded csv file. I would like to decode it and concatenate it into one string and return it. After that I am trying to subsrciibe to that method and click the DOM to download. I get empty string with only `"\r\n"` in it. Why doesn't it wait for REST to return the file before returning?

```
downloadFilesAndConcatenate(): Observable<any> {
    let concatenatedFileDecoded: string = '\r\n';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.fileIDs.length; i++) {
      this.restService.getFile(this.fileIDs[i]).subscribe(response => {
        this.fileResultSet = response;
        this.message = response.message;
        this.file = this.fileResultSet.result;
        let fileCSVbase64 = this.file.fileBytes
        let fileCSVDecoded = atob(fileCSVbase64);
        concatenatedFileDecoded += fileCSVDecoded;
      },
      error => {
        this.message = error.error.message;
      });

      return new Observable( observer => {
        observer.next(concatenatedFileDecoded)
        observer.complete();
      });
    }
  }
```

And then I subscribe to it:

```
download() {
    if (this.dateEnd !== null && typeof this.dateEnd !== "undefined") {
      debugger;
      this.downloadFilesAndConcatenate()  // Multiple files
        .subscribe( 
          (result) => {
            debugger;
            const link = document.createElement( 'a' );
            link.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild( link );

            const blob = new Blob([result], {type: 'text/csv'});
            const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 

            link.href = objectURL;
            link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download =  this.file.name;
            link.click();
          },
          (err) => {
            console.error(err);
          },
          () => console.log("download observable complete")
        );
    } else {
      this.downloadFile();  // Only one file
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because it is asynchroniuos code. it is expected that sync code will be executed earlier than async.
correct code would be like this

```
downloadFilesAndConcatenate(): Observable<string> {
    return forkJoin(this.fileIDs.map(id => this.restService.getFile(id))).pipe(
      map(responses => '\r\n'+responses.map(r => atob(r.result.fileBytes)).join(''))
      catchError(e => this.message = e.error.message)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Implemented `catchError` and imported `forkJoin` from RxJS. However, for second `map` (in pipe) I get `Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?ts(2552)
lib.es2015.collection.d.ts(36, 13): 'Map' is declared here.` If I do that, then I get: `Value of type 'MapConstructor' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?`

Comment: it should be also imported from rxjs as well as catchError

Comment: Tnx, imported from here `import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: All files are downloaded and joined in one csv. It's working, thank you!